# Docker: What's available in the parent image?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-image

In docker how do I know what packages are available in the parent image I am using?
I am trying something like:

```
docker search python
```

but I get some (network?) error.
I have the image locally. How would I search what packages I can use?

Answer (score 1):

`docker search` is the command you use to search for docker images on the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

If I understood well your question, given an image (say `alpine:latest`) you want to know what's inside that image.

If that's the case, the only thing you can do IMHO is just run the container and explore it.

You can do that for the alpine:latest image with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -ti alpine:latest ash
```

You'll get a prompt inside an instance of the mentioned image and you can dig around to check what's available.

There is no place where you can access informations about the content of an image in a structured way.

Comment: So there is no way to know if python is installed unless I run a container? Also what is `ash`?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. ash is a shell that ships by default in alpine linux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell

Comment: You potentially can check github for the dockerfile and check how they build the image (https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/build for alpine) - but that does not really speed up the process.